# How to migrate a grunt project into ember-cli project

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, migrate

I have a js project using ember.js, which is  managed by grunt. But when ember-cli is trend of ember.js management tool, I want to migrate the existing grunt project into ember-cli project.

According to the ember-cli manual, I tried the [Ember CLI migrator](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-cli-migrator), but it require the existing project is a git version-controlled project, otherwise it cannot migrate. Is there a good way to migrate the existing project without git repo?

Comment: why not run `git init` in the directory and then delete the `.git` directory afterwards. Otherwise I fear it'll have to be manual labour :)

Comment: The git repo doesn't have to exist, just init it locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, the following operations should be proceeded:

1. install git;
2. git init
3. git add
4. git commit -m "anything"

That's all.